# OnBackPressed Minimizes the app

Tags: android, android-navigation

I click on **Settings button** *(new activity is presented to me)* then I click on **Android Home button** *(minimizes the app)* then I **select** my app **from thestack**. I press **back arrow** (/or back), which minimizes my app *(it should return me back to previous activity)*. There is no way I to go back only to kill the application.

I have parent activity defined in Manifest also it works well if I don't minimize application from **Settings Activity**.

Comment: Could you post the corresponding source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this for **parent** activity in manifest (in my case MainActivity)
from: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
to: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
and it works well.

full code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
    <activity
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"/>
```